# Name of a set satisfying the partition problem

Tags: terminology, discrete-optimization

In the partition problem one asks whether a given set of numbers can be partitioned into two sets $S_1$, $S_2$, with a property that elements of $S_1$ sum to the same value as elements of $S_2$.

My first question is how do we call a set satisfying such a property, i.e. a set for which the partition problem has a solution?

Let $\vartheta = \{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_N\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and 
\begin{equation}
\delta (\vartheta) \equiv \min_{\varsigma \in \{\pm 1\}^{N}} \left| \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \varsigma_i \alpha_i \right|.
\end{equation}
Obviously $\delta (\vartheta) = 0$ if, and only if the set $\vartheta$ has this property. Otherwise $\delta (\vartheta) > 0$.

My second question is how do you call this quantity, $\delta (\vartheta)$? Is there a standard notation for it?

Please, note that in the standard partition problem in the complexity theory one considers sets of integers, whereas here I would like to consider sets of real numbers.

Comment: "Discrepancy" may be a good one. It's used for [similar quantities](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~zdvir/apx11slides/bansal-scribe.pdf).

Comment: Also, your question is unclear as to whether you want to name the *sets* or $\delta(\vartheta)$.

Comment: I would like to have proper names for both of them.